# Confirm box appear two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

Here is my code :

```
if (confirm("Voulez vous sauvegarder avant de quitter ?") == true) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Ajax call
  },500);
}
else {
// Do nothing
}
```

When the comfirm box appear, I press cancel, but the confirm box appears a second time, I think it's not because of the setTimeout because it only goes in when I press Ok and here I press Cancel .

I think it's not a major issue but for user experience that's no a good thing

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The problem isn't in the quoted code.

Comment: Side note: `if (confirm() == true)` is pointless. `confirm` already returns a boolean, just `if (confirm())`. I mean, if you don't trust booleans, where do you stop? `if ((confirm() == true) == true)`? `if (((confirm() == true) == true) == true)`? :-)

Comment: Can you please add the code (trigger event) where this is getting executed. The problem must be with your trigger event

Comment: I tried the same code and it didn't happen to me. You must have something else rather than the above in your code.

Comment: booleans... I can never trust something so absolute. -_-

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hq28x14z/    #values is a <select>